# Trouble Getting Child Form to Center to Maximized Parent

Tags: c#, winforms, position

I have a form application that starts maximized, and a child form is supposed to appear in its center to ask for a password.  However, it only works, if the `WindowState` property of the parent for is set to `Normal`.  When I set it to `Maximized` on my two-monitor system the parent form appears on one screen and the child form appears centered to the second screen.  Does anyone know how to get this working properly, so that the child form appears centered over the maximized parent form?

```
public partial class MyUI : Form
{
    PasswordCheckForm PasswordCheck = null;

    public FactoryTestToolUI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PasswordCheck = new PasswordCheckForm();
        PasswordCheck.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        PasswordCheck.Show(this);
    }
}

public partial class PasswordCheckForm : Form
{
    public PasswordCheckForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.CenterToParent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the parent form in the child form, and set the parent location to the child and then center it.

```
Location = parentForm.Location;
CenterToScreen();
```

You can send the parent form in the constructor.

```
new PasswordCheckForm(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It does get the child form on top of the parent form (same screen), but the child form is being painted in the far upper-left of the screen.